# close fullscreen of Youtube Player on back button inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, master-detail

I am using *Master/Detail* layout in a tablet, on the left few buttons to open several fragments, one of the fragments contains youtube player.

**The Problem,**

When the youtube player is full screen, and i press back button, The *activity* `onBackPressed` is called, and the whole activity is closed.

**What i have tried,**

1- Added on KeyListener for parent fragment (which contains the Youtube Fragment) and handle when click on back button, but this listener is called only if the player is not fullscreen, otherwise it is not called,

```
rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        rootView.requestFocus();
        rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    try {
                        // Close full screen
                        return true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        AHHExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

2- Added onKeyListener to youtubeFragment View to check if it is full screen then close the full screen mode

```
youTubeFragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
youTubeFragment.getView().requestFocus();
    youTubeFragment.getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                                                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                                        try {
                                                            youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(false);
                                                            return true;
                                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                                            AHHExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            });
```

And this is also not called in all cases.

I need to handle the hardware back button while the youtube player is in fullscreen, the fullscreen mode is closed and the application is in its previous state.

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**
- I want to handle this inside the fragment, instead of handling it in the parent Activity, I already handling it inside the parent activity, but I don't like this solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this other than what you described here or adding  youtube-specific code in the Activity onBackPressed?

Comment: No, I couldn't find another solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `onBackPressed()` in your activity and in case your player is in fullscreen, you can handle it there as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (youtubePlayer != null && isFullscreen) {
        // if fullscreen, set fullscreen false
        youtubePlayer.setFullscreen(false);

    } else {
        // if NOT fullscreen, perform default call on back press
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

> **P.S.** In above code fragment, `isFullscreen` is instance variable of our
>   activity and is synced with `youtubePlayer` state from within
>   **`OnFullscreenListener`** set on `youtubePlayer.setOnFullScreenListener()`.
>
> Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: The activity has no relation with the youtube player, the youtube player is inside fragment, And i don't want to handle this in the activity. I need to make code independent as i can.

Comment: The youtube player is in relation with the activitys context. Wish the best of luck to find what you are searching for.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to Andre's reply.

In your parent Activity add:

```
public YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
public boolean isYouTubePlayerFullScreen;
```

In your fragment add:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

Then, on `YouTubePlayerFragment` initialization:

```
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean b) {
        mainActivity.youTubePlayer = player;
        player.loadVideo(videoId);

        player.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                mainActivity.isYouTubePlayerFullScreen = b;
            }
        });

    }
```

Now your `Activity` has access to `YouTubePlayer` and information if player is full screen or not.

Next, inside your `Activity`, override `onBackPressed` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (youTubePlayer != null && isYouTubePlayerFullScreen){
            youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(false);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer missing the static modifier for the public variables youTubePlayer & isYouTubePlayerFullScreen

Comment: @EmadMorrisZedan, please elaborate why they have to be static.

Comment: Awsome answer, thanks
Also you need to put in manifest file

 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">